# Problema na verificação do método

Tags: c, booleano

Fiz essa função para o jogo da velha:

```
void jogadaPC(char m[][3], char opc)
{

    puts("\nVez do computador.");
    sleep(1); 

    int linha = rand() % 2;
    int coluna = rand() % 2;

    bool vazio = localVazio(m, linha, coluna);
    bool valido = false;

    if(!vazio)
    {
        while(!valido)
        {
            linha = rand() % 2;
            coluna = rand() % 2;
            if(localVazio(m, linha, coluna))
            {
                m[linha][coluna] = opc;
                valido = true;
            }
        }
        return;
    }
    m[linha][coluna] = opc;
}
```

Em que ele escolhe uma posição(linha, coluna) aleatoriamente na matriz, e se for falso passa por a verificação do while, mas ele nunca termina.

Assim: iniciei todos os valores da matriz com ' ':

```
void iniciar(char m[][3])
{

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            m[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }
}
```

Mas ele não esta passando nesse método aqui:

```
bool localVazio(int m[][3], int lin, int col)
{
    return m[lin][col] == ' ';
}
```

Que por padrão retornaria true para vazio.

Comment: Que linguagem de programação está utilizando? C?

Comment: O problema provavelmente é na `localVazio()` que nunca retorna `true`. Este código certamente pode ser bem simplificado, mas só podemos ajudar sabendo da parte onde há erro. Veja como fazer um [mcve].

Comment: E por quê linha e coluna são obtidos a partir de um resto de divisão por 2? A variável `m` é 2x2?